# Error exponentiation in Haskell does not result in error

Tags: haskell

I noticed that if you run `error "Error 23" ^ 0` in Haskell then it will return `1`. I presume this is because it sees the zero in the exponent and decides to return 1 right away. Why is this, and is there some way to recover the error and error out with that instead?

Comment: It will first inspect the second parameter, and if it `0`, it returns `1`. Often one does not use `error` to specify computations that fail, but `Maybe` or `Either`.

Comment: Thanks. I'm following some tasks in a textbook, and one of them was to return with an error if certain things happend i.e (2/0)^0 should give a division by zero error, but it looks like i have to maybe nest some case statements to make sure the first parameter runs first

Comment: `error` doesn't return an error; it hides it from the type system.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Why is this

Because `x^0 = 1` holds (mathematically speaking) *always*, so there's no point evaluating `x` first. In most languages, this kind of *shortcut behaviour* is only supported in built-in operations like C/Javascript/...'s `? :` operator, but in Haskell any user-defined function can shortcut unnecessary work too, thanks to laziness. The fact that this actually allows surpressing ⊥ values such as `error` in the base argument of `^` may be soldom relevant, but the fact that this can shortcut *a lengthy computation* can be quite handy indeed. (The official semantics of Haskell don't talk about *lengthy computations* but rather about strictness and ⊥, but often the advantages of laziness are really more about avoiding finite, but unnecassary-long computations.)

> is there some way to recover the error and error out with that instead

Well, you can always explicitly introduce strictness using [`seq`](https://wiki.haskell.org/Seq):

```
Prelude> let x = error "Error 23" in x `seq` (x^0)
*** Exception: Error 23
CallStack (from HasCallStack):
  error, called at <interactive>:2:9 in interactive:Ghci2
```

Comment: Might be worth mentioning that `seq` forces evaluation of its first argument before its second argument can be evaluated.

Comment: @bradrn I deliberately did not go into any explanation of what `seq` does (except that it works in this example) but only linked to the HaskellWiki, because the simple “eval LHS before RHS” explanation is somewhat inaccurate/misleading. That's rather what `pseq` does, but also not quite.

Comment: I’d be interested to know how that explanation is misleading — that’s how I learnt about `seq`.

Comment: @bradrn first, it only evaluates the LHS to WHNF, which is often not what one would intuitively understand as “evaluated”. And then, as long as the compiler is able to prove that the LHS is not ⊥, it is at least in theory free to completely ignore the `seq`.

Comment: Yes, I am aware that it is evaluated to WHNF: that’s what I meant by ‘evaluate’ in my earlier comment. But I haven’t heard that the compiler may ignore the `seq` if the LHS isn’t ⊥ — do you have a reference where I can read more about that?

Comment: @bradrn: The [Haskell wiki page on `seq`](https://wiki.haskell.org/Seq) says the same thing. `seq` is defined in the [Haskell 98 Report §6.2](https://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/basic.html) by the equations `seq ⊥ _ = ⊥; seq a b = b`, in particular, it doesn’t specify *which* bottom you get (``error "A" `seq` error "B"`` is implementation-defined) and there’s nothing else special about `seq` that makes it not subject to demand analysis; if it’s known that `a` has not evaluated or will not evaluate to ⊥, then the compiler is free to ignore the `seq`, since the difference isn’t observable.

Comment: Not sure how correct this is, but my mental model is that ``s = a `seq` b`` makes `s` depend strictly on *both* `a` and `b`, while ``p = a `pseq` b`` makes `p` depend strictly on *only* `a` *before* returning `b`.